# Switch an ItemTemplate text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to show a list of descriptions coming from a webservice call. I choose to show them on a ItemControl.

To simplify let's say that the data are in the form:

```
public class Voce
{
    public string Ita { get; set; }
    public string Eng { get; set; }
}
```

The XAML code for the control is:

```
   <ItemsControl x:Name="table" Margin="20,70,20,92" Background="#FFFFF3F3">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="myDesc" Text="{Binding Ita}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Of course I set:

```
private List<Voce> listaVoci;
...
table.ItemsSource = listaVoci;
```

This is working correctly and set to Ita field.

Now I need to switch the texts and show the Eng fields (following a button click) inside the same List<> but I don't know how. I tried with this:

```
    Binding binding = new Binding("Text")
    {
        Source = listaVoci,
        Path = new PropertyPath("Eng")
    };
    SetBinding( TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

but, of course, there is not the reference to the internal TextBlock ..

Or is it better/simpler to separate the descriptions into two Lists and switch the table.ItemSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `DataTrigger` to the template and bind to some property that decides which value to display.

In the following example I use the `Tag` property of the `ItemsControl` to do this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="table" Margin="20,70,20,92" Background="#FFFFF3F3">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Ita}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, 
                                            Source={x:Reference table}}" Value="Eng">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Eng}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You then simply set the property in your button click event handler to display the value of the `Eng` property of the `Voce` object:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    table.Tag = "Eng";
}
```